# How do you split a dataframe according to an element contained in one of two different columns?

Tags: r, list, split, subset

I have a large data frame which I wish to split into different (smaller) data frames that contain an element in either of two different columns.  Assume I have a data frame like the one below:

```
v1     v2      v3       v4       v5
mom    dad     2        4        5
bro    mom     5        3        4
sis    dad     3        4        2
bro   sis      3        7        9
```

I want to split this into 4 separate data frames one for each of the unique values in v1 or v2.  The new data frames should look like:

```
$mom
v1     v2      v3       v4       v5   
mom   dad       2        4        5
bro   mom       5        3        4

$dad   
v1     v2      v3       v4       v5   
mom    dad      2        4        5
sis    dad      3        4        2

$sis 
v1     v2      v3       v4       v5   
sis    dad      3        4        2 
bro    sis      3        7        9

$bro  
bro    mom      5        3        4
bro    sis      3        7        9
```

I was able to do this using a for loop but I want the end output to be a list so that it is easy perform functions over each element.  The for loop I have used looks like this:

```
for(i in 1:length(us)){
    subset.dataframe <-dataframe[dataframe$v1 == us[i] | dataframe$v2 ==    us[i],]
 }
```

where the "us" is a vector of the unique values from both (v1 and v2) columns combined.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: From the overly-complicated-code department - `c( split(df, pmax(df$v1, df$v2)), split(df, pmin(df$v1, df$v2)) )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `lapply` to loop through `us` and subset the original data frame which will return a list of data frames. Suppose `df` is your data frame here:

```
us = unique(c(df$v1, df$v2))
setNames(lapply(us, function(e) subset(df, v1 == e | v2 == e)), us)

$mom
   v1  v2 v3 v4 v5
1 mom dad  2  4  5
2 bro mom  5  3  4

$bro
   v1  v2 v3 v4 v5
2 bro mom  5  3  4
4 bro sis  3  7  9

$sis
   v1  v2 v3 v4 v5
3 sis dad  3  4  2
4 bro sis  3  7  9

$dad
   v1  v2 v3 v4 v5
1 mom dad  2  4  5
3 sis dad  3  4  2
```

Comment: I ended up using this method. I really like the simplicity of this. Thank you for the information.

Comment: Can I ask what is the     function(e) doing? Is the 'e' just dummy variable?

Comment: `function(e) subset(df, v1 == e | v2 == e)` this is an anonymous function in R. `e` is the function parameter. When we use `lapply` to loop through `us`, e will take value from `us` one by one.

Answer (score 1):

We can also do by looping over the `unique` value of `unlist`ed first two columns, then use `which` with `arr.ind = TRUE` to get the rows index and subset the rows of 'df1'

```
Un1 <- unique(unlist(df1[1:2]))
setNames(lapply(Un1, function(nm) df1[which(nm == df1[1:2], 
             arr.ind = TRUE)[,1],]), Un1)
#$mom
#   v1  v2 v3 v4 v5
#1 mom dad  2  4  5
#2 bro mom  5  3  4

#$bro
#   v1  v2 v3 v4 v5
#2 bro mom  5  3  4
#4 bro sis  3  7  9

#$sis
#   v1  v2 v3 v4 v5
#3 sis dad  3  4  2
#4 bro sis  3  7  9

#$dad
#   v1  v2 v3 v4 v5
#1 mom dad  2  4  5
#3 sis dad  3  4  2
```